# Excel-External Data Properties-Best Option if: If the number of rows in the data range changes upon refresh:

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-transfer

I've linked an excel file to an MS Access query and there are 3 options in the "External Data Properties" dialogue box. The dialogue prompt is "If the number of rows in the data range changes upon refresh:" Following this prompt are 3 options.

1. Insert cells for new data, delete unused cells
2. Insert entire rows for new data, clear unused cells
3. Overwrite existing cells with new data, clear unused cells

These options all seem to do the same thing, just in slightly different ways. I can not figure out which, if any, is the best option for my purpose.  Does one option take more time or use more memory? What is the benefit of one option over another?  I've search the web and  everything I found describes the operation and not why you would want to select one operation over another.

Comment: Why don't you try them all and find which one suits your needs? I don't think performance is a big factor here.